# Merge python list by specific indexes

Tags: python, list

I have an array, where I want a specific index to be merged.

```
["captain:", "robot", "alpha", "beta:", "gama", "delta:", "fighter", "test", "exp"]
```

the idea of this, every even element should contain : and the rest of the elements should not contain :

The output I want:

```
["captain:", "robot, alpha", "beta:", "gama", "delta:", "fighter, test, exp"]
```

considering the array is changeable, for example, the array could be:

```
["captain:", "robot", "beta:", "game", "exp", "delta:", "fighter", "test"]
```

the output should be the same, each even with : and odd index without :

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Any efforts? Code?

Comment: @OlvinRoght the only thing I can think of is to find the index, for example, find the index of elements with : and check the index of elements between them and merge them but I wasn't able to implement this so far :(

Comment: You can start from retrieving indexes of elements which contains trailing colon. [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) could be helpful.

Comment: yes, I can also use `if ':' in array`, but again not sure how do I merge the ones between them without a colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation using `groupby`:

```
import itertools
x = ["captain:", "robot", "alpha", "beta:", "gama", "delta:", "fighter", "test", "exp"]
new_list = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(x, key = lambda string: string.endswith(':')):
    if key: # in case you happen to consecutive values that end in a colon
        new_list += list(group)
    else: # these elements do not end in a colon
        new_list.append(', '.join(group))
print(new_list)
# ['captain:', 'robot, alpha', 'beta:', 'gama', 'delta:', 'fighter, test, exp']
```

Here, the grouping key checks to see if the item ends in a `":"`, if it does, `key` is `True`, otherwise it is `False`. If consecutive values of `key` are the same, they are put in the same group. Thus, any number of elements following a string containing a colon will be grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.groupby()` has you covered.

```
lst = ["captain:", "robot", "alpha", "beta:", "gama", "delta:", "fighter", "test", "exp"]
print([', '.join(g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda s: s.endswith(':'))]) 
# ['captain:', 'robot, alpha', 'beta:', 'gama', 'delta:', 'fighter, test, exp']
```

Comment: I'd use `for _, g` *(imho)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght By doing this is the idea that we also change g[1] to g. Does for _, g unpack the elements in the groupby as individual elements in the returned tuple? I am reading the groupby docs right now and I have trouble understanding why they don't just return the grouper iterator

Comment: @RichardKYu, I thought it's obvious. `groupby()` returns pairs where first element is a key and second element is an iterator with all elements grouped by this key. While in this particular case we don't need it key is necessary in many cases, especially when you perform some data modifications in function passed as key argument and want to use modified data.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about the groupby function. So, here is an alternative approach, in case anyone was interested:

```
sample = ["captain:", "robot", "alpha", "beta:", "gama", "delta:", "fighter", "test", "exp"]


def find_next_index(sample, start):
    for i in range(len(sample)):
        if i>start and ":" in sample[i]:
            return i, ", ".join(sample[start+1:i]), False
    
    return start, ", ".join(sample[start+1:]), True


result = []
start = 0
while True:
    x,y,z = find_next_index(sample, start)

    result.append(sample[start])
    result.append(y)
    start = x
    if z:
        break
    

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['captain:', 'robot, alpha', 'beta:', 'gama', 'delta:', 'fighter, test, exp']
```